# NullBooleanField doesn't show None state after saving in the django admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm trying to represent a simple NullBooleanField in the django.

`BOOL_CHOICES = [(True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No'), (None, "Unknown")]`

`handicap_accessible = models.NullBooleanField(default=None, blank=True, null=True, choices=BOOL_CHOICES)`

in the django admin when i select the unknown radio button for None and save it, it clears the selection but still shows up null in the database. Not sure if this is a known bug with django NullBooleanSelect widget or not but i can't seem to find a solution to this issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you set `blank=True`? Looks to me that this has impact on the fact that they add a "blank" option.

Comment: so you want `None` and it is `null` in database, which is actually `None`. What's the problem?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem blank = True is simply used for by the django admin for validation purposes. The reason i have it there is so if they forget to the enter an option it won't force them to, instead it'll default to null=True.

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov The issue is that i the admin it isn't visually represented to the user that the field is indeed Unknown because the Unknown radio button is not selected. Even though in the database it shows null.